# Finding one function that can satisfy both of these equations

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

I have two equations as follows:
$$2f'(x)-\sqrt x\ln x=0$$
$$f(e)=0$$
But I'm not sure how I can find one function $f$ to satisfy both since the second equation has different variables. I've tried isolating $f'(x)$ on the first one, and then trying to find $f$ through integration but I don't think that's right.

Thanks  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integration is the right way to go for this problem.
$$2f'(x)-\sqrt x\ln x=0$$
$$f'(x)=\frac12\sqrt x\ln x$$
$$f(x)=\int\frac12\sqrt x\ln x\,dx$$
$$=\frac12\left(\frac23x^{3/2}\ln x
-\int\frac{\frac23x^{3/2}}x\,dx\right)$$
$$=\frac12\left(\frac23x^{3/2}\ln x-\frac49x^{3/2}+K\right)$$
$$=\frac13x^{3/2}\ln x-\frac29x^{3/2}+K$$
Since $f(e)=0$:
$$0=\frac13e^{3/2}\ln e-\frac29e^{3/2}+K$$
$$K=\frac29e^{3/2}-\frac13e^{3/2}=-\frac19e^{3/2}$$
Finally we have
$$f(x)=\frac13x^{3/2}\ln x-\frac29x^{3/2}-\frac19e^{3/2}$$

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to write that, I'm surprised I was half on the right track haha. And a big thanks to the other commenters too!

Answer (score 1):

You need to integrate the first equation (indefinite integration) and remeber to include constant in your answer.

Then put the condition of second equation to find the value of constant.

F(x) = ((ln(x) * x^(3/2)) - (2 * x^(1/2))) /2+ c

Putting x = e, satisfy f(x) = 0.

Thus, c = - e^(1/2) * (e - 2) * (1/2)

Note: beware of the brackets.

Comment: Proper MathJaX formatting would greatly improve your answer, FYI.

Comment: Oops, got some calculation error

Comment: Thanks btw. Actually I'm new here. Learning to format like you guys

Comment: You can hit "edit" on any post and see the way it is formatted, FYI.

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x) =\frac{1}{2}\int \sqrt{x}\ln xdx=\frac{1}{3}x^\frac{3}{2}\ln x-\frac{1}{3}\int x^\frac{1}{2}dx=\frac{1}{3}x^\frac{3}{2}\ln x-\frac{2}{9}x^\frac{3}{2}+C$$

Using the constraint $f(e) =0$, $C=\frac{-2}{9}e^\frac{3}{2}$.